A branched covering map is determined by the corresponding subgroup of the fundamental subgroup of the base
Let $f:X^n\to Y^n$ be a $d$-fold branched covering along branch locus $B\subset Y$. This is by definition a smooth proper map with critical set $B$ such that $f:X-f^{-1}(B)\to Y-B$ is a $d$-fold covering map, and for each $p\in f^{-1}(B)$ there are local coordinate charts $\subset \Bbb C\times \Bbb R^{n-2}$ about $p$ and $f(p)$ on which $f$ is given by $(z,x)\mapsto (z^m,x)$ for some positive integer $m$ called the branching index of $f$ at $p$.
In p.225 of the book 4-manifolds and Kirby calculus by Gompf and Stipsicz, it is written that, given $(Y,B)$ with $\dim Y\leq 4$ or $B$ embedded, the branched covering $f:X\to Y$ ($X$ connected) is completely determined by the index $d$ subgroup $\pi_1(X-f^{-1}(B))\subset \pi_1(Y-B)$, since $X-f^{-1}(B)$ is determined, and the circle bundle $\partial \nu B$ determines a circle  bundle structure on $f^{-1}(\partial \nu B)$, which can be uniquely filled in by a $D^2$-bundle.
I can see that the subgroup $\pi_1(X-f^{-1}(B))$ determines $X-f^{-1}(B)$ (because a connected covering space is determined by the corresponding subgroup of $\pi_1$), but I cannot see why $f^{-1}(B)$ is determined. Where did the assumption that "$\dim Y\leq 4$ or $B$ embedded" have been used to conclude that "the circle bundle $\partial \nu B$ determines a circle  bundle structure on $f^{-1}(\partial \nu B)$, which can be uniquely filled in by a $D^2$-bundle"?

Take two such branched covering maps, construct a diffeomorphism of open and dense subsets and argue that it is locally uniformly continuous, hence, extends to a continuous map. Then analyze it local properties at the ramification locus and argue that the extension is a local diffeomorphism. It is a long proof...
